# Do I need to rename vector.js for custom Mediawiki style based on Vector?

Tags: vector, mediawiki

My question is simple, do I need to rename vector.js file when I create a skin based on Vector? Let me explain more on how I created my custom skin...

I have created a custom skin for my Mediawiki and its based on Vector. My skin works almost exactly like Vector but with css tweaks and with changes to the html template elements inside the skin template which is basically moving around the elements and displaying a bit different that the way it is done in Vector. I read the following tutorials when creating my template:

1. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning/Tutorial
2. http://blog.redwerks.org/2012/02/28/mediawiki-subskin-tutorial/

These are the things I did when creating the custom skin:

1. I copied and pasted the Vector folder and then renamed it to 'myskin'.
2. I then created the 3 files, skins/myskin/myskin.php, skins/myskin/MySkin.skin.php and skins/myskin/MySkin.i18n.php like its mentioned in the tutorial link above.
3. I then renamed the key, identifier and name of my skin from vector to MySkin or myskin like its mentioned here:

   > "When building a skin you'll be working with your skin name in three
   >   forms, a lower-cased key, a camel cased identifier, and a localized
   >   skin name. For our skin the key would typically be 'myskin', the
   >   identifier 'MySkin', and the localized name 'My Skin'.
4. I edited the screen.css and tweaked it to the style I want.
5. I then edited the skin template. Here instead of using "class SkinMySkin extends SkinVector", I copied the "class MySkinTemplate extends BaseTemplate" section from Vector and re-arranged the templates and tweaked it to create my skin.

After doing all of the above, everything works. However, I noticed that when I copied all the files from Vector to MySkin, there is this "vector.js" file in it too. I dont know if I need to rename this js file to myskin.js or do I leave it like this. Currently I did not rename this javascript file and everything seems to be working fine anyways. So I am not sure what this file does. I read the tutorials and also searched MediaWiki and it doesnt mention anywhere if I need to rename this file to myskin if I am creating a skin based on Vector. I also dont see a link or reference to this file inside my skins/myskin/myskin.php, skins/myskin/MySkin.skin.php and skins/myskin/MySkin.i18n.php files. Can someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Check your browser's console log.  You'll probably see that it is requesting vector.js still.

Comment: thats a good idea :) I had a look at the source from my browser but I dont see the vector.js being used. So does it mean that its not required then? What does this file do?

Comment: Reading it shows that it takes care of menu drop-downs and collapsible tabs.

Comment: I dont have collapsible tabs. But I thought collapsible tabs were vector extensions here and not included as default: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Vector However the menu drop down for the action buttons works even when vector.js isint loaded. May be the action down down is just css based. hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

I have also created a custom skin with the manual like the OP. I didn't rename vector.js and everything seem to work fine for me.

You could simply rename or move vector.js and check if you notice any missing functions or weird behaviour in either the following functions

- Collapsible tabs
- Focus search input at the very end
- animate  drop down menu in and out
  or
- Always collapse if the "More" button is already shown

Since this is more or less all the .js seems to do + providing some fallbacks.